# Visualforce page not rendering with wrapped header

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I have a visualforce page with showheader set to true. But I see the page rendering with the tabs in header not wrapping

Comment: Are you using jquery document event in page

Comment: @Tushar Sharma No I am not using jQuery . Though I have standard JS window.onload = function() {}

Comment: Using window.onload will break the standard onload function. Use window.addEventListener instead.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks sfdcfox and Tushar Sharma for quick turnaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use this structure, you overwrite any existing listeners:

```
window.onload = function () { }
```

Instead, look at [best way of unobtrusive onload in plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274374/best-way-of-unobtrusive-onload-in-plain-javascript):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", new function (){}, false);
```

Comment: There's really no need to mention attachEvent, as no browser that salesforce supports supports attachEvent, and not addEventListener...

Comment: Ah didn't realize it doesn't apply to 9+. @sfdcfox

Comment: @Adrian Larson That solves the issue.

Comment: @AdrianLarson We are finally out of the stone ages of browsing... and it only took a decade or so.

Comment: I was so excited when they finally dropped support for IE versions that should have been axed so many years sooner. At least it's done.